# How to make one executable file that has a bash script and dependency files?

Tags: bash, batch-file, exe

Here is my bat script (TestBatScript.bat):

```
set /p args=Enter some args:
TestApp.exe %args%
pause
```

For this script to work I have to have TestApp.exe and TestBatScript.bat in the same folder. Is it possible to include these two files in one file .bat or .exe or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are asking for, you can't aggregate batch file with exe file. Indeed exe file are compiled file (open it on a text editor, you won't be able to read it). Batch files are scripts that are interprated by terminals.
If you can recompile your exe file, you can add to source code to pass argument with hands (for instance use scanf in C, ...) if there is no argument passed by the system

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   if(argc==0) {
      /* get here the argument (no argument passed)*/
   }else {
      /* use here argument passe to your function */
   }
   /* Do stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Iexpress` that is a built in program in your windows OS. To access it hir <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then type `iexpress` or `iexpress.exe`. Do some experiments and you will eventually understand. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress) is the Wikipedia in case want it. And [Here](https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_jeXX2c_VAhXKQI8KHY18Aw4QFggvMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikihow.com%2FMake-an-Exe-File&usg=AFQjCNF_7ZmNtQkDeczohyxFPqJjE9wzDg) is a tutorial on How to use it.